# Creating column of rankings without resetting index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Jim', 93, 87, 66], ['Bob', 88, 90, 65], ['Joe', 72, 100, 70]], columns=['Name', 'Overall', 'Stopping', 'Playing'])
```

I want to create a dataframe such that each subject has a ranking out of 3 according to their score on `Overall, Stopping, Playing`.

This is the desired output:

```
df_ranked

Name  Overall  Stopping  Playing
 Jim        1         3        2
 Bob        2         1        3
 Joe        3         2        1
```

I believe this can be done by sorting the dataframe by each column "ascending", resetting the index, then creating column of index values.

**Is it possible to approach this another way?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same answer as @Timeless using `rank` but showing how you can select which columns to rank and editing your `df` in place instead of creating a new table

```
#select columns for ranking
rank_cols = ['Overall', 'Stopping', 'Playing']

#rank those columns in reverse order as ints and assign back into the df
df[rank_cols] = df[rank_cols].rank(ascending=False).astype(int)
```

Comment: I've created this dataframe as a reproducible example but in my actual code the columns are named differently. I have changed the names of them now.

Comment: changed the answer. you just need to find a way to select the columns you want to rank as a list. This answer edits your `df` instead of creating a new `df_ranked` like @Timeless's answer which you may or may not want

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`pandas.DataFrame.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) :

```
to_skip = ["Name"] # <- add here more columns, if needed

df_ranked = df.set_index(to_skip).rank(ascending=False, method="min").reset_index()
```

Output :

```
print(df_ranked)

  Name  Overall  Stopping  Playing
0  Jim      1.0       3.0      2.0
1  Bob      2.0       2.0      3.0
2  Joe      3.0       1.0      1.0
```

Comment: What about in the case where there are other columns in the dataframe that don't need to be ranked?

Comment: Use `.join`. I updated my answer.

Comment: I've created this dataframe as a reproducible example but in my actual code the columns are named differently. I have changed the names of them now.

Comment: No problem, use `df.filter(like="Score")` I will update my answer to match your new output.

Comment: Apologies, I have edited once more without "Score"